# Getting static values from class in android

Tags: java, android, oop, static-variables

Static variables or static method can be called without creating its class instance.  Which means its values are same for all objects or any reference to that class. Does it mean we can get static values from class anywhere in our project.
In my case when user login I get all of the profile information and assign it to static variables in UserProfile.java class.  Can these values be accessed anywhere in my project. 
I don't want to use Shared-preferences or SQlite for storing this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static variables are accessible directly from class without creating an object of class.

- Variables you want to access must be public

you can simply access them like

```
YourClass.yourVariable
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, static variables can be accessed directly from the class' name (`MyClass.myVariable`), as long as their access policy permits it.

Answer (score 1):

If those static values are public then you can access them from wherever you can access your class.
However, you cannot access classes across different modules, so to make that happen , you have to add  compile project(':project_name') in your dependencies inside your gradle file.